# Determine if the starting date is before ending date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table named data with columns: CD, beginDate, endDate. suffix. I need to determine if any row I want to insert, the beginDate is earlier than endDate in any other row with the same suffix value.

Code with what I am trying and no luck:

```
select * from data a1
join data a2 on a2.cd=a1.cd
where
    a1.suffix=a2.suffix and 
    a1.beginDate<a2.endDate
```

Any idea, hot can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but your description tell that there is one table, but there is 2 tables in SQL. Please, make the question clearer. And if you can, add some examples of input and output data.

Comment: @Parandroid there is one table, and I need to select all data from table, where the beginDate is before startDate and the suffix value is the same

Comment: The same as what? And why you join table a2 in your SQL, what is that second table a2?

Comment: Where are you inserting the data from? At present, your query is comparing the existing table with itself - surely you won't be reinserting from the same table?

Answer (score 1):

You want an inequality on the cd condition in the join:

> ...the beginDate is earlier than endDate in any **other** row with the
>   same suffix value.

You can also put all of the conditions into the ON clause of the join:

```
select a1.cd, a2.cd, a1.suffix, a1.beginDate, a2.endDate
from data a1
join data a2 
on a2.cd <> a1.cd
and a1.suffix = a2.suffix
and a1.beginDate < a2.endDate
```